# How to run "deploy a package step" on Octopus server same as script task step

Tags: octopus-deploy, dbup

We are using octopus deploy as Continuous delivery. We have already setup all web related configuration on octopus "Deploy Package Step" where we are deploying nuget package to octopus server and then it is deploying the application to multiple server nodes.

Now we are planning to implement database automation using DBUP on octopus server.We are creating a nuget package and using "Deploy.ps1" which contains the power shell command to execute the console exe application on server.

We are using "Deploy Package step " for the same we don't want to install tentacles on DB server we want to use the same connection string which is already configured for our web application. We have just created DB user with DDL access(Create,Alter..).

As for our web environment we have multiple VM in environment so we don't want to execute the script on multiple environment.

with "Deploy Package" step on octopus we are not getting any option where we can configure to execute the package on octopus server.

Please share your thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am an Octopus employee.

I'd recommend using the "Run a script" step rather than "Deploy a package" for your SQL deployment.  This step allows you to run the script on the Octopus server, and the script can still be inside a package.

Feel free to also reach out to us at our usual support channels such as our support forum or email. Details at https://octopus.com/support

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

- As @JaydenPlatell mentioned, `Run a script` step and then you can select the feed and package. Though in that case your deployment script has to be part of the package itself.
- Have a tentacle installed on 1 deployment machine (for example could be the same as Octopus Server). Give it a role of "DB deployer" or similar and use it for deploying. Benefit of this is that you can have one DB deploy" `Script module` shared for different deployment projects.

Comment: I have multiple scripts which i am grouping in to the nuget package. In Run a Script step I am not able to find where i can select the feed as  package. we tried to install tentacle on octopus server but getting issue job keeps on running without throwing any exception.

Comment: i tried by adding Run a Script step and able to select the package . but i am facing issue with octopus job as  is not stopping after executing the script it's keep on running. i had to manually cancel the job.

Comment: sounds like a script issue itself? have you just tried running the script manually? Manually from that box?

Comment: thank Alex .. it is working the issue was with console application. Removed the console.readline()